# How to remove /public/ from url in Slim?

Tags: php, .htaccess, slim

I threw the site on hosting, server and I have a problem. And exactly, the site url is launched by:

```
site.com/public/
```

And i wanna to work without public like this:

```
site.com/
```

I maked site by Slim 3. I have **public** folder where is **index.php** and **.htaccess** file.
My .htaccess file looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So.. i tried makes 20 different versions of .htaccess, but it dosen't work. How can i get url withous /public/ folder?
I add a photo of the folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTX70.png)

*edit*: i forgot about one thing, exactly when i was coding site i always running her by php built-in server by command: `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` and it's work's without **/public/**

Comment: Just set the `DocumentRoot` to the `public/` directory on your webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/public/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```